# how to make jQuery run immediately on pageload?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jquery, which checks whether there is content in 2 inputs (it's a login page with username and password) and adds the class "used" if there is content.

```
$(window, document, undefined).ready(function() {
  $('input').blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val())
      $this.addClass('used');
    else
      $this.removeClass('used');
  });
});
```

The problem is that it only adds the class `used` to the second input after there has been a click event on the page, ie. if I click on any part of the page, it adds the class `used`.

The first input (username) is in focus on page load and it gets the class correctly, while the password field does not get the class `used` unless I have clicked somewhere, or unless I put focus in the input.

What is missing? How can I make the jQuery detect that there is content on the input, as soon as the page loads?

Comment: It's because you're using a `blur` event. That will only fire when an element loses focus - in the case you mentioned, because you clicked somewhere else. You'll need to better describe what you want to achieve if you want someone to suggest an alternate solution

Comment: Also, why are you issuing an `$(undefined).ready()`?

Comment: I want the 2 inputs (username and password) to have the class "used" if they have content in them

Comment: @minitauros I was trying various ways to get the jquery work on page load and I was trying various stupid ways I guess

Comment: You should namespace your blur event and then trigger it on document ready

Comment: @aliengirla.k.a.alienno.155 thanks for clarifying. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using a blur event. That will only fire when an element loses focus - in the case you mentioned, because you clicked somewhere else

> I want the 2 inputs (username and password) to have the class "used" if they have content in them

If that's your intention then you can extract the logic out to a function which you call when the page loads and also when the value of the elements changes. I'd also strongly suggest you use a `input` event for this as it covers all key events and pasting content using the mouse.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('input', setClass).each(setClass);

  function setClass() {
    $(this).toggleClass('used', $(this).val().trim() != '');
  }
});
```

```css
input { width: 50px; }
.used { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="aaa" />
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="bbb" />
```

Note that I've made a couple of amendments to your logic. Firstly I used a standard document.ready handler. Your original was needlessly convoluted. Secondly you can provide a boolean to `toggleClass()` without the need for the `if` condition.

Comment: Quick question: Does the input event fire when the browser retains the input Data during page reload? If not then input needs toggling at document ready does it not?

Comment: The `input` event does not fire on load, but I've catered for that as code is run on document.ready (see the function call in the `each()`)

Answer (score 0):

Just Try it, get all `input` element in `map` as well as `each loop`

```
$('input').on('keypress', function() {
  $("input").map(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val())
      $this.addClass('used');
    else
      $this.removeClass('used');
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that `map()` is intended for creating arrays from a collection of elements. While this will work it's not the correct usage of the function. I'd suggest you use `each()` instead. Also note that this doesn't work on load of the page as the OP requested